# Why my search bar is not working?

Tags: ios, swift, searchbar

I have tried to solve this for a couple of hours. I am a newbie in IOS and want to develop a bucket list with a search bar. The codes have no problem in compilation but when i make input in the search bar, it won't show any search result. I don't know where the problem is.

btw: I have two suspects:
1. I tried to print the status, and it seems the searchBar is never active. How to open it?
2. Does it have anything to do with var missions' data 
type as Mission? It is something I am not familiar with.

Please see the following codes:

```
import UIKit

class BucketListViewController:UITableViewController, MissionDetailsViewControllerDelegate, MissionEditViewControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate{

    var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    var searchActive : Bool = false
    var filtered:[String] = []
    var missions:[String] = ["Sky diving", "Live in Hawaii"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchBar.delegate = self
        self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = true;
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filtered = missions.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
            let tmp: NSString = text
            let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
            return range.location != NSNotFound
        })
        if(filtered.count == 0){
            searchActive = false;
        } else {
            searchActive = true;
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // dequeue the cell from our storyboard
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell")!
        if(searchActive){
            print("search active!")
            cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = missions[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(searchActive){
            return filtered.count
        } else {
            return missions.count
        }
    }



    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "AddNewMission" {
            let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! MissionDetailsViewController
            controller.delegate = self
        }
        if segue.identifier == "EditMission" {
            let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! MissionEditViewController
            controller.delegate = self
        }
    }


    func missionDetailsViewController(controller: MissionDetailsViewController, didFinishAddingMission mission: String) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        missions.append(mission)
        tableView.reloadData()}

    func missionEditViewController(controller: MissionEditViewController, didFinishEditingMission mission: String, atIndexPath indexPath: Int) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        missions[indexPath] = mission
        tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

[image: PICTURE ON WORKING ERROR OF SEARCH BAR]

Comment: Perhaps your search bar isn't hooked up properly to the IBOutlet in your storyboard?

Comment: I think I have hooked it up by @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar! How can I check on it?

Comment: @marshall have you checked `textDidChange` method is getting called ?

Comment: @Rajat i tried to print something out but found it is not working, why? I have used this search bar codes in my previous project and it has worked before.

Comment: @marshall `print(searchBar)` before `searchBar.delegate = self` and check whether it is nil or not

Comment: Can you share demo app? @marshall

Comment: @Rajat Thanks for the reminder. It seems I have mistakenly commented out searchBar.delegate =self. I have corrected it and I can have input into the search bar. However, no matter what I have put in the search bar, still no search result shown. I have print the status and found search bar is running. Also, as a side note, the first letter in search bar is always changed to a capital letter. This has not happened before and I don't know why.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni No problem. How to share it with you? Sorry I am a newbie in SO.

Comment: just zip it and upload it here http://www.tinyupload.com/ and share link

Comment: @DharmeshKheni  http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=06622464785759372987

Answer (score 0):

From the project you have shared there is a problem in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

replace

```
cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row] as? String
```

with

```
cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row].details
```

And it will work fine.

Your complete code will be:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // dequeue the cell from our storyboard
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MissionCell")!
    // if the cell has a text label, set it to the model that is corresponding to the row in array
    if(searchActive){
        print("search active!")
        cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row].details
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = missions[indexPath.row].details
    }
    return cell
}
```